# Chinese character in nodejs response write

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jsdom

I cannot display chinese character response to browser using nodejs ?

```
jsdom.env({ html: 'http://www.baidu.com',
    scripts: ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js']
}, function (err, window) {
    //Use jQuery just as in a regular HTML page
    var $ = window.jQuery;

    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8" });
    res.end($('title').text());
});
```

Incorrect result : �ٶ�һ�£�����֪��

Correct result should be : 百度一下，你就知道

Comment: Are you able to print to console correctly?

Answer (score 1):

因为百度的网页编码是GBK的

because the charset of baidu.com is GBK

Comment: Already set gb2312 or GBK still same.

result : 锟劫讹拷一锟铰ｏ拷锟斤拷锟斤拷知锟斤拷

Comment: I believe nodejs only supports UTF8. Check the source.