# Why can't I write Chinese characters in nodejs HTTP response?

Tags: node.js, utf-8, cjk

Here is my little code:

```
var http = require('http');
var port = 9002;
var host_ip = '<my_ip>';
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var content = new Buffer("Hello 世界", "utf-8")
    console.log('request arrived');
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Encoding':'utf-8',
        'charset' : 'utf-8',
        'Content-Length': content.length,
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end(content.toString('utf-8'),'utf-8');
}).listen(port, host_ip);
console.log('server running at http://' + host_ip + ':' + port);
```

Previously I just let `res.end` to send "hello world" and it worked well. Then I wanted to adjust a little bit and changed the 'world' into the Chinese equivalent '世界', and so changed the 'charset' 'content-type' in the header to 'utf-8'. But in Chrome and Firefox I see this:

```
hello 涓栫晫
```

However, amazingly opera(11.61) does show the correct result `hello 世界`. I want to know whether I have missed something in the code, and why this is happening. Thank you guys.

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698552/chinese-character-in-nodejs-response-write) is similiar with my situation but not exactly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Problem is with the character set specification. For me it works with this change:

```
'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'
```

Tested with Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

You could also look into the node.js package "express" which allows rewriting your code like this:

```
var express=require('express');

var app=express.createServer();

app.get('/',function(req, res) {
    var content = "Hello 世界";

    res.charset = 'utf-8';
    res.contentType('text');
    res.send(content);
});

app.listen(9002);
```

Comment: well, I know express and webjs , I just try to do same exercise and suddenly come across this strange problem~ :)

Answer (score 2):

`content-encoding` is not a character set but a encoding of http response itself

`charset` is not a common http header

`content-length` is unneccesary here

as @jjrv said, you should write `'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'` there

Comment: Your are right, fistly I thought as the manual say without `content- length` it will be a chunked packet and I guess it won't display the chinese charater correctly. But after add 'charset=utf-8' to `Content-Type`, I omitted the `content-length` field and it did work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`涓栫晫` is actually `世界` in encoding GB-18030, and then displayed as UTF-8. Probably the characters got saved in that encoding.