# How to display some Chinese characters in the console of node.js

Tags: node.js

[Why can't I write Chinese characters in nodejs HTTP response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470426/why-cant-i-write-chinese-characters-in-nodejs-http-response)

In the above link, they are able to send the response and display it in a web browser. How do I display the same response text in my node.js console?

Comment: This question is incomplete. What have you tried? What OS are you running? What font do you use for the console etc?

Comment: i am working on windows 7.. and all i need is to display Chinese characters on my node.js console..

Comment: I suggest you complete your question with that info.

Comment: var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var content = "Hello 世界";
    console.log(content);
 
    
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/'); when ever i try to print the value of content .. i am getting the following the output .. o/p : Hello and 2 square boxes followed by Hello..